# Conversion of $F(x) = {1 \choose 0} (2t^2 - 3t + 1) + {3 \choose 1} (4t - 4t^2) + {1 \choose 2} (2t^2 - t)$

Tags: polynomials, coordinate-systems

I have a textbook with a calculation step that is pretty unclear to me:

$$F(x) = {1 \choose 0}  (2t^2 - 3t + 1) + {3 \choose 1}  (4t - 4t^2) + {1 \choose 2}  (2t^2 - t)$$

$$= {-8 \choose 0}  t^2 + {8 \choose 2}  t + {1 \choose 0}$$

I guess there is some very simple math involved that I just don't know at all :.-(

Comment: I have changed the formatting of the title so as to make it take up less vertical space -- this is a policy to ensure that the scarce space on the main page is distributed evenly over the questions. See [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9730) for more information. Please take this into consideration for future questions. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sorry, these are not binominal coefficients, it should be coordinates. How can I enter this properly?

Comment: They are column vectors multiplied by scalars. So for example
$${3\choose 1}(4t-4t^2)={-12t^2+12t\choose -4t^2+4t}.$$ Similarly with the other terms. "Unpack" them in the end. Sensing that someone is already typing an answer :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Coordinate-wise, you have

$$F_1(t) = 1(2t^2-3t+1)+3(4t-4t^2)+1(2t^2-t) = 2t^2-3t+1-12t^2+12t+2t^2-t$$

Group like terms:

$$F_1(t) = -8t^2+8t+1.$$

Perform a similar association with the second "row".

Comment: Ok that's dead easy, but I was searching for some magic all the time, because I thought I can not mix up all my coordinates and create 3 "new" ones.

Comment: The coordinates were your "vertical" terms, the horizontal grouping didn't matter. Typically, we don't write it quite like this, or we make it clear that the parenthetical terms are in fact coordinates. It might have been more clear if the polynomial terms were put before the coordinates, e.g. $$(4t-4t^2)\left[\begin{array}{c}3 \\ 1\end{array}\right].$$